# A generally usable pandas DQL/DML?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrames and would like to give (trusted) users the ability to query and modify them in an easy way, for eg. from a web UI with natural expressions supporting (somewhat) complex transformation rules.
I'm seeking for something, which makes this possible.

Pandas offers a query language, which supports operations like these:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(-2, 5),
                   'b': range(10, 3, -1),
                   'c': range(10, 3, -1)
                   })

df.query('a < 0 and b> 7')
```

Pandas also have eval, so I can do this:

```
df.query('a < 0 and b> 7').eval('d = a + b')
```

which will assign `a+b` to a new column `d` on rows, which match the query.

Both query and eval supports basic operators, so this seemed to be a good start for filtering rows and making modifications to them.
However I need arbitrarily nested `min()` and `max()` functionality, like:

```
df.query('a < 0 and b> 7').eval('d = max(min(a*2.25, b + 10000), c * 0.6)')
```

but I couldn't find a way to do that and multiple assignment (eg. `d = max(min(a*2.25, b + 10000), c * 0.6); e = a+b`)support.

The farthest point I could get is the following on this path (which seems to be wrong to me):

```
df.eval('d = @min(a, b)', local_dict={'min': np.minimum, 'max': np.maximum}, engine='python')
```

but I have the following problems with that:

1. it works only with the (slower) `python` engine, not with `numexpr`
2. I have to prefix the operation with a `@`
3. there is no multiple assignment support (ie. `d = a+b; e=min(a, b)`)
4. this doesn't work: `@min(a, b*1.25)`

The latter raises the following error:

> AttributeError: 'BinOp' object has no attribute 'value'

So my question after the trip described above is:
is there a generally usable DQL/DML for pandas, which I can give to the users to define filtering/modification rules for existing DataFrames?